# How to format the output print statement to print linked list?

Tags: python, data-structures

So I trying to print the linked list after the string but I not able to do it.
The print statement is in pop function inside unordered class

The linked list always get printed first and then the string
i.e

```
54 26 56 93 17 77 31 7
Original Linked List: None
```

My Desired Output

Original Linked List: 54 26 56 93 17 77 31 7

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext

class UnorderedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while (temp):
            print(temp.data, end=" ")
            temp = temp.next
        print('\n')

    def pop(self):
        print('Original Linked List:' self.printList())
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current.getNext() != None:
            previous = current
            current = current.getNext()
        previous.setNext(current.getNext())
        print('New linked list after pop is:', self.printList())
```

So I have tried formatting it with

```
print(f'Orginal Linked List: {self.printList()})
print('Original Linked List: %d' %(self.printList()))
```

Nothing really works
I am new to programming
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function that *returns* a list rather than *printing* a list.  It's easiest if you name this function `__str__` because then it'll get called automatically whenever anything tries to convert your list to a string.

Change:

```
    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while (temp):
            print(temp.data, end=" ")
            temp = temp.next
        print('\n')
```

to:

```
    def __str__(self):
        s = ''
        temp = self.head
        while temp:
            s += str(temp.data) + " "
            temp = temp.next
        return s[:-1]
```

and then you can do:

```
print(f'Original Linked List: {self})
```

which will automatically call your `__str__` method and put the result into the f-string.

Comment: Thank you so much!
It worked
Now I can also print linked list
using
print(mylist)